# HTML gallery have a 4 columns and not 3

Tags: html, css

I need to know that as it is determined that these lines of code contain 4 columns. I need this to be flexible. Since in some cases I occupy only 2 or 3 images. The problem I have is that no matter how many images you call, the container always contemplates having 4. I can not figure out how to modify this. I would appreciate your help.

```
<ul class="photo-gallery">
    <li>
        <figure>
            <div class="gallery-item">
                <a href="Asphalt_A3.jpg">
                    <img src="lTireBtn1.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                        <div class="centrize">
                            <div class="v-center">
                                <i class="hc-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </a>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <div class="gallery-item">
                <a href="Asphalt_A2.jpg">
                    <img src="TireBtn2.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                        <div class="centrize">
                            <div class="v-center">
                                <i class="hc-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </a>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <div class="gallery-item">
                <a href="Asphalt_A1.jpg">
                    <img src="TireBtn3.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>
                        <div class="centrize">
                            <div class="v-center">
                                <i class="hc-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </a>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In plain HTML the answer is: you just manually add or remove columns accordingly. If this HTML is produced by some sort of generator, like PHP, ASP .NET, JSP that's a totally different question.

Comment: How can find this php js and css?

Comment: What do you mean by "how find this php js and css"? These are technologies you could use to build websites. You could learn them anywhere, there's plenty of texts and tutorials on the web.